# read csv file using column names in java

Tags: java, csv, file-io, opencsv

I have a .csv file with hundreds of rows and many columns. i want to read specific columns from the file. These are the column names i have.

productId   title   imageUrlStr mrp price   productUrl  categories  productBrand

from this i want to read all the columns i did it by this way

```
final String DELIMITER = ",";
        try
        {
            String line = "";
            //Create the file reader
            fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToParse));

            //Read the file line by line
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String name,imgURL,productURL,price;
                String[] images;
                //Get all tokens available in line
                String[] tokens = line.split(DELIMITER);
                name=tokens[1];
                images=tokens[2];
```

it goes like this. but the problem is token[2] which is column 'imageUrlStr' has multiple values which is seperated by coma.AND I JUST WANT THE FIRST VALUE FROM THAT COLUMN. and there is no fixed number, some has 3 values in that columns and some has 4 etc. so i cant just separate that value again using coma to get the FIRST VALUE AND and go to the next column.
My question is Can i separate and split using column name in a CSV file. so specified column name will store to a string and then take another to another string. so i can split the value of imageurlstr and take the first value and then go to next column.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use Acpache Commons CSV.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is structured properly, than you have all this imageUrlStr values in Quotes like: "url1, url2, url3", otherwise you have a problem in your CSV format.

There are number of libraries like:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

You can even use regexp for parsing. For example `"(?:\\s*(?:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"|([^,]+))\\s*,?|(?<=,)(),?)+?"`

Comment: I am getting the values like you said inside the double quotes

Comment: Than, I suggest you look at existing libraries or adapt your solution.